# Where I can check hardcoded password for Strapi development?

Tags: javascript, strapi

Is there anyway that I can look out for hardcoded password that I had set-up when I was configured strapi ?

Actually few week back I configure the strapi backend with one of my next js project but now I have forgot the password for that particular user and also I have provided some random email, so , i cannot recover through forgot password step. Does strapi hardcoded my password somewhere in strapi folder at the time of set-up authentication ?

Answer (score 0):

if you have an access to the database you can see the email and get the hash of the password then you can try **bcryptjs** to change your password.

check https://hashinteractive.com/blog/strapi-change-admin-password-in-mongo-database/